# Leave - one - out - Cross Validation KNN R

Tags: machine-learning, r, cross-validation, k-nn

I have a dataset and I divided it into test data and train data. Can anyone suggest how to perform LOOCV for KNN regression? Is there any library?

```
val(train.data,train.label,K,numfold)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DMwR/versions/0.4.1/topics/loocv

Comment: It is not what I want!!!

Answer (score 1):

To learn how its done, simplest way is to give a try on sklearn and then try to implement the same by yourself-

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html

and a very basic level explanation  here-
https://medium.com/@svanillasun/how-to-deal-with-cross-validation-based-on-knn-algorithm-compute-auc-based-on-naive-bayes-ff4b8284cff4

Answer (score 1):

`caret` can use LOOCV as its trainControl method:
https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#the-traincontrol-function